# how to give instruction before application launch WP7.?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to show some instruction once in a while,
when application installed and start to run the application that time I have 3 screeen shots image one by one user tap on image it will forward to next image so how I can do this into windows phone 7.?

Note : this is only first time when app install and have look.

Thank you..!

Comment: what have you tried? Why is just displaying images with `Tap` events to dismiss tham and a value in ApplicationSettings to track first run not enough?

Answer (score 0):

May be you could create a `UserControl` which displayed when your MainPage has jus loaded.

Comment: I want only first time application launch.! this is call every time whenever user can load applicarion.

Comment: Yea probably you'l have to store a bool value in the IsolatedStorage to check if the app is installed or not. For the first time initialize  it to true. And the when you save save it as false. So on subsequent launches, the value is false and so dont display the control. So somethin which follows in the same line

Answer (score 0):

Make another xaml page and redirect user to it in case it is a first launch of the application.

In a loaded event of the newly created page put this code:

```
 NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
```

That should be it.